# Single table DynamoDB design tips

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have an old application I am modernizing and bringing to AWS. I will be using DynamoDB for the database and am looking to go with a single table design. This is a multitenant application.

The applications will consist of Organisations, Outlets, Customers & Transactions.
Everything stems from an organization, an organization can have multiple outlets, outlets can have multiple customers and customers can have multiple transactions.

Access patterns are expected to be as follows:

- Fetch a customer by its ID
- Search for a customer by name or email
- Get all customers for a given outlet
- Get all transactions for a customer
- Get all transactions for an outlet
- Get all transactions for an outlet during a given time period (timestamps will be stored with each transaction)
- Get all outlets for a given organisation
- Get an outlet by its ID

I've been reading into single table designs and utilizing the primary key and sort keys to enable this sort of access but right now I can't quite figure out the table/schema design.
The customer will have the outletID and OrganiastionID attached so I should always know those ID's

**Data Structure (can be modified)**

Organisations:

- id
- Name
- Owner
- List of Outlets
- createdAt (timestamp)

**Outlets:**

- OrganisationId
- Outlet Name
- Number of customers
- Number of transactions
- createdAt (timestamp)

**Customers:**

- id
- OrganisationID
- OutletID
- firstName
- lastName
- email
- total transactions
- total spent
- createdAt (timestamp)

**Transactions:**

- id
- customerID
- OrganisationID
- OutletID
- createdAt (timestamp)
- type
- value

Comment: In my opinion you need at least 2 or 3 tables for all your data and data access patterns. Why do you feel the need to restrict everything to a single table?

Answer (score 4):

You're off to a great start by having a thorough understanding of your entities and access patterns!  I've taken a stab at modeling for these access patterns, but keep in mind this is not the only way to model a solution.  Data modeling in DynamoDB is iterative, so this is *very* likely that this specific design might not fit 100% of your use cases.

With that disclaimer out of the way, let's get into it!

I've modeled your access patterns using a single table named `data` with global secondary indexes (GSI) named GSI1 and GSI2.  Each GSI has partition and sort keys named GSI#PK and GSI#SK respectively.

[image: base table]

The base table models the following access patterns:

- Fetch customer by ID: `getItem where PK=CUST#<id> and SK = A`
- Fetch all transactions for a customer: `query where PK=CUST#<id> and SK begins_with TX`
- Fetch an outlet by ID: `getItem where PK=ORG#<id> and SK = A`
- Fetch all customers for an outlet: `query where PK=OUT#<id>#CUST`

That last access pattern may require a bit more explanation.  I've chosen to model the relationship between outlets and customers using a unique PK/SK pattern where PK is `OUT#<id>#CUST` and SK is`CUST#<id>`. When your application records a transaction for a particular customer, it can insert *two* records in DDB using a batch write operation.  The batch write operation would perform two operations:

- Write a new Transaction into the Customer partition (e.g. PK = `CUST#1` and SK = `TX#<id>`)
- Write a new record to the CUSTOMERLIST partition (e.g. PK = `OUT#<id>#CUST` and SK = `CUST#<id>`).  It this record already exists, DynamoDB will just overwrite the existing record, which is fine for your use case.

Moving onto GSI1:

[image: GSI1]

GSI1 supports the following operations:

- Fetch outlets by organization: `query GSI1 where GSI1PK = ORG#<id>`
- Fetch transactions by outlet: `query GSI1 where GSI1PK = OUT#<id>`
- Fetch transactions by outlet for a given time period: `query GSI1 where GSI1PK=OUT# and GSI1SK between  and

And finally, there's GSI2

[image: GSI2]

GSI2 supports the following transactions:

- Fetch transactions by organization: `query GSI2 where GSI2PK = ORG#<id>`
- Fetch transactions by organization for a given time period: `query GSI2 where GSI2PK=OUT#<id> and GSI2SK between <period1> and <period2>`

For your final access pattern, you've asked to support searching for customers by email or name. DynamoDB is *really* good at finding items by their primary key.  DynamoDB is *not* good for search, where fuzzy or partial matches are expected.  If you need an exact match on email or name, you could do that in DynamoDB by incorporating email//name in the primary key of the User item.

I hope this gives you some ideas on how to model your access patterns!

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, this answer is fantastic and just what I was after. Thankyou!

Comment: I'm glad this helped!  Consider accepting my answer if it addressed your concerns.

Comment: @SethGeoghegan I'm, also trying to learn single table design - are you able to share what software you used to generate those screenshots?